# From Eventbridge to Redshift through Rule

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-event-bridge, event-bus

I am trying to send data from an API-triggered event to Amazon Redshift using an EventBridge rule. However, I am unable to see any data in the Redshift table.
Event bus has been created and through target rule trying to insert data into table.

Background:
I have set up an API endpoint that triggers events when certain actions occur.
I have configured an EventBridge rule to capture these events and send them to a Redshift cluster for storage and analysis.
The EventBridge rule is configured with the necessary permissions and target settings to interact with Redshift.
The Redshift cluster and target table have been set up with the appropriate schema to receive the event data.
Expected Outcome:
When the API-triggered event occurs, the event data should be captured by EventBridge and sent to the Redshift table.
The data should be inserted into the target table, allowing further analysis and processing.
Current Observation:
Despite the event being triggered and the EventBridge rule being in place, no data is being inserted into the Redshift table.
I have verified that the event payload is correctly formatted and contains the necessary data for insertion.
The Redshift cluster and target table are properly configured and accessible.

SQL Statement 1:
INSERT INTO wallet_dev_transactions(transactionid)
SELECT
json_extract_path_text(event::json, 'detail', 'transactionId') AS transaction_id
FROM default;

SQL Statement 2:
INSERT INTO public.wallet_dev_transactions (transactionid) VALUES('1');

Created Full access role for this purpose.

Expected Outcome:
When the API-triggered event occurs, the event data should be captured by EventBridge and sent to the Redshift table.
The data should be inserted into the target table, allowing further analysis and processing.